# Multi Screen support for OpenFrameworks Android Application

Tags: android, java-native-interface, openframeworks, projector, multiscreen

I'm using 'OpenFrameworks for Android'. I need two OFActivities (in Android) to be running parallelly.. Any idea how I can acheive this?

The goal is to use 'DisplayManager' to display --
1. OFActivity1 (UI + preview of Camera)         -   on Android phone
2. OFActivity2 (Resulting output due to UI) -   from an external projector

If it helps, I am looking to split this project - http://code.google.com/p/structured-light/ to two screens but on Android. The porting has been completed by now.

Comment: Not sure -- I'd recommend posting this question to http://forum.openframeworks.cc